# Get the parent directory of a soft link

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, links

I have the following directory structure

```sh
[xss]# tree /etc/test
/etc/test
├── challenge
│   └── domain.tld
├── domains
│   └── domain.tld
├── users
│   └── puff
│       └── domain.tld -> /etc/test/domains/domain.tld
```

And I'm trying to find the parent directory of a soft link matching `domain.tld`

ex: I want to know in what folder of `/etc/test/users` is `domain.tld` found

In this example is `puff`

So far I got to:

```sh
find /etc/test/users -type l -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld | grep domain.tld
# output lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 May  3 15:30 /etc/test/users/puff/domain.tld -> /etc/test/domains/domain.tld
```

LE:

```sh
find -L /etc/test/users/ -xtype l | grep domain.tld | sed 's/etc\/test//g'
#output - //users/cb/domain.tld
```

Comment: Do you want the link name or the target name to match?

Comment: target directory

Answer (score 0):

With find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0, you can try this way :

```
dirname $(find /etc/test/users -lname *domain.tld)
```

Comment: no match :(, can you see my LE, on original post ?

Comment: @AlexanderBr.Sorry, perhaps i don't understand. I create somewhere a file domain.tld. I create a symbolic link to this file in a subdirectory of somewhere. With my command, I get the directory of the symbolic link from a parent directory of somewhere. With your command from LE, i get a lot of files witch are not symlinks. First you tell about /etc/test/users, after you tell about /etc/xss/users/. Perhaps your question is unclear.

Comment: that was my bad :) fixed now

Comment: with your command, i don't get any results - so i've come up with this version - `find /etc/xss/users -lname *domain.tld` and I do get `/etc/test/users/puff/domain.tld`

I only want to output **puff** - as in domain.tld belongs to user puff

Comment: @AlexanderBr. You are right, i don't know why there is a . in my answer. Update it.

Comment: @AlexanderBr. Now, if you only want puff, try user=$(find /etc/xss/users -lname *domain.tld);user="${user%\/*}";echo "${user##*\/}"

Comment: it shows just **domain.tld** - you also forgot the `*` in front of domain.tld :D